# React Native The View Doesnt Work On If Statment

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

```
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
                    setSelectedValue(itemValue); 
                    if(itemValue == 'other'){
                        alert('You Choose: '+itemValue+' Nice')
                        
                        return(
                            // The <View> Doesnt Work Why ????
                            <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',height:5000,width:5000,}}>
                                <Text>Anas</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                        
                    }
                    
                }}
```

The  Doesnt Work Why ????
i cant put it in if statment or i can ?
i dont hava idea !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a small sandbox where you can see an example of how to achieve what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bird-lzzbb

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

  const onValueChange = (itemValue) => {
    setSelectedValue(itemValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        onPress={() => onValueChange("other")}
        title="Click to set value to 'other'"
      />
      {selectValue === "other" ? (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 5000, width: 5000 }}>
          <Text>Anas</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can use the `onValueChange` function to pass it as callback in any event you want (like the `onPress` of that button I have created) but then you need to return all jsx in the return of your functional component (or the `render` function if you're using class components)